# Angular : Call Function from different component with Service Sharing

Tags: angular, service, angular5, angular6

I want to achieve this -

```
// component1
load(){ 
  // code... 
}

// component2
component1.load();
```

So, basically I just want to call function of different component from a component.

I have read through the internet that there are 3 ways to share data between components, In my app, I am using Service Sharing to share data between my components.

But how I can simply call a function from different component with service sharing approach ?

Comment: Are these components related to each other? Is there a parent-child relationship between them?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Nope, they are siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following service based on observables. It's using messages as string, but you can make it more generic if you need to pass data between components. In my normal services, I usually pass a message that contains message type and message data for instance

Basically, one component compoennt broadcast a message, and the other one listen to messages

Try this

**message-service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";


@Injectable()
export class MessageService
{
  //subject to trigger events
  private mySubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<string>();
  //observable to listen to events
  public readonly messageReceived$: Observable<string> = this.mySubject.asObservable();

  //
  brodcast(message: string)
  {
    this.mySubject.next(message );
  }
}
```

**component1.ts**

```
constructor(private service: MessageService){}
//...
this.service.broadcast('triggerLoadMethod'); //broadcast a message for service subscriber to receive
```

**component2**

```
constructor(private service: MessageService)
{
    //subscribe to observableto receive messages
    this.service.messageReceived$.subscribe( message =>
        {
        if(message == 'triggerLoadMethod') //if we are interested in the message, process it
        {
            this.load();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but can you explain your solution with comments what is the flow and which line is doing what?, that will be more helpful.

Comment: I added some comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorSubject`. Here's how.

App Component Template:

```
App Component!

<hello></hello>
<sibling></sibling>
```

EventService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  event: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  emitEvent(data) {
    console.log('next Called with ', data);
    this.event.next(data);
  }
}
```

HelloComponent:

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

```
import { EventService } from './event.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.event
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data received', data);
        this.someMethod(data);
      });
  }


  someMethod(data) {
    console.log('some method got called!', data);
  }

}
```

Siblingcomponent:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { EventService } from './event.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sibling',
  template: `<button (click)="onClick()">Call Hello Component's Method</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class SiblingComponent  {

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  onClick() {
    console.log('onClick Called');
    this.eventService.emitEvent({ foo: 'bar' });
  }

}
```

Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufszmd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you generally call the method directly. Its good to keep separation of concerns. The best way is to use observables to handle this.

Service:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventService {

  myEvent: Subject<void>;

  constructor() { 
     this.myEvent = new Subject<void>();
  }

  getEvent() {
      return this.myEvent.asObservable();
  }

  callEvent() {
      this.myEvent.emit();
  }


}
```

Component1:

```
constructor(private eventService: EventService);
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.subscribe(event => this.load())
} 

load() {

}
```

Component2

```
constructor(private eventService: EventService);
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.callEvent();
}
```

This way component2 can publish the event anytime it wants. For that matter, any component can call the event anytime it wants. And Component1 can subscribe to the event. For that matter, any component can subscribe to the event. So the code is more extendable and more maintainable.

Comment: Well, I like the way of separation of concern, but in your solution, can you explain a little bit more what if we have multiple events ? how will you identify different events here if you have one single event service and if our objective is to maintain separate event service to handle events sharing ?

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question with more concrete examples. In general, I would try to make each service have a single responsibility. So I quite often use a NavbarEvent service in my sites so that I can open and close a side navbar from different components. You might also want a AuthService, so that a login page and a registration page could both publish a login event. And lots of services might subscribe to that. An AuthService might also have a logout event. You could try to make something generic that published an Event with a type, but I would avoid that if possible.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your answer, but in EventService I received an error which was : "emit does not exist on type Subject<void>" and I change it to next base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54654828). but when I tries to use "eventService.subscribe" in ngOnInit method  in Component1 I got error that subscribe does not exist on type EventService. What did I miss? @bgraham